# Django website saying "Page not found (404)"

Tags: python-3.x, django

I just deployed a django website that I made. This is my first time of doing something like this.. still a newbie. The problem is that whenever I try to upload something to the website, I get the following error while DEBUG is True

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://majestylink.com/admin/music/music/add/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view
Using the URLconf defined in majestylink.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='index']
advertise/ [name='advertise']
about-us/ [name='about-us']
promote/ [name='promote']
privacy-policy/ [name='privacy-policy']
s/ [name='search']
admin/
poem/
video/
music/ [name='index']
music/ <slug:slug>/ [name='detail']
ckeditor/
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, music/music/add/, didn't match any of these.
```

The code below is my music app url..

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    path('<slug:slug>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

]
```

And this one is my project url..

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('poem/', include('poems.urls')),
    path('video/', include('video.urls')),
    path('music/', include('music.urls', namespace='music')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What else am I supposed to do in order to be able to publish something on the website? Am still new so I have a limited knowledge on how these things works

Everything works fine on local server, I get any error while testing it on local machine.
I made a slight change while deploying the website which is **changing the database** from the default **sqlite3** to **MySQL**, will this be the cause? If yes, how can I resolve it. All migrations were run successfully

Comment: Yes, because your server or Django-project don't have this end-point /admin/music/music/add/

Comment: But it runs fine on development server. What am I supposed to do please

Comment: advertise/

about-us/

promote/

privacy-policy/ 

s/

admin/

poem/

video/

music/


music/ <slug:slug>/ 

ckeditor/

^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

You have this endpoints you can use any one of this.

Comment: Or create this endpoint /admin/music/music/add/

Comment: I've added some more information to the question. You can now see my ```urls.py``` files. How can I create the endpoint? @Abhishek Patel

Answer (score 1):

Your URL points to a admin/music/music/add path. I'm guessing you meant admin/music/add. You may want to share the template that triggers the add command.

Comment: No template for that yet, am still using the admin interface (domain_name/admin/). My confusion is that everything works fine on my local machine

Comment: The link is generated automatically whenever am trying to save a new post. I started seeing the error as soon as I changed my database from sqlite3 to MySQL